# ALB configuration route53 for subdomains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have example.com domain and its pointing to  to the ApplicationLoad balancer (A record)

I have 3 subdomains.

logs.example.com, web.example.com, users.example.com

If user enters the above, it should be resolved to Application Loadbalancer. How can i resolve this, as i can't create multiple CNAME's for the load-balancer.

I have following in route53

```
A  example.com alb-21212122.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

Which records should i add to satisfy the above.

Comment: you need to add a `*.example.com` wildcard record to route 53.  You'll need a corresponding certificate in ACM to match `*.example.com` or the three specific hostnames `logs`, `web`, `users`.

Comment: @erik258, Thanks, so need to create *.example.com as CNAME for example.com  ? This is a private hosted zone.

Comment: Either that or an ALIAS which is generally preferable